# Why bundler can't resolve dependencies with prerelease versions?

Tags: ruby, version, bundler, versioning, beta

This way:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5.0.beta'
gem 'json_spec'
```

It doesn't work:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rspec-core":
  In Gemfile:
    json_spec was resolved to 0.1.0, which depends on
      rspec (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
        rspec-core (= 2.0.0)

    rspec-rails (~> 3.5.0.beta) was resolved to 3.5.0.beta1, which depends on
      rspec-core (= 3.5.0.beta1)
```

This way:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5.0.beta'
gem 'rspec', '~> 3.5.0.beta'
gem 'json_spec'
```

It works. Why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the [related](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2938) [issues](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4340):

> > This is deliberate. Rubygems explicitly excludes prereleases unless the version requirement has an alphabetical number in it. So your version requirements, as stated, are actually in conflict. If you want a prerelease, use '>= 2.2a'.
>
> I see how prerelease versions are complicated and what I'm about to say could cause problems but what I expected ">=2.2" to mean is a) "anything released 2.2 or greater" and b) "don't get a prerelease version on my account but if some other gem wants one I'm willing as long as its above 2.2". It seems that it only means (a).
>
> The problem gets more difficult when the dependency is not in my Gemfile but in a gem I use and I can't change the version to ">=2.2a".